# Dynamic XML element names based on object property value in runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, xmlserializer

Say I have a structure like

```
    public class Data
    {
        public string ElementName { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class XmlDoc
    {        
        public List<Data> Elements { get; set; } = new List<Data>(new[] { new Data { ElementName = "A", Content = "CA"}, nnew Data { ElementName = "B", Content = "CB" } })
    }
```

Is there a way to make the serialized format look like

```
<XmlDoc>
    <A>CA</CA>
    <B><CB></CB>
<XmlDoc>
```

?

The gist being that the tag names are generated dynamically from the collection items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to create  XmlDocument and add the element according to your XmlDoc class property.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
     XmlDoc x1 = new XmlDoc();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
       
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement(typeof(XmlDoc).Name);
        foreach (var item in x1.Elements)
        {
            XmlElement newelement = doc.CreateElement(item.ElementName);
            newelement.InnerText = item.Content;
            root.AppendChild(newelement);

        }

        doc.AppendChild(root);

        doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I did about this. I think the easiest way without writing some special handlers. :)